# Displaying the same data in Modal form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am working on an online store react project where my part is to add Discount for products.

For that i developed a component which has details of products including a Add Discount button. Once we click the button it takes us to a modal form in which we can add a discount to the product. It's that simple.

This is my code for the component.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
    import { getCategories, getProducts } from "../core/apiCore";
    import EditProduct from './EditProduct';


    const Product = props =>{

        return(
        <tr>
            <td>{props.product.category.name}</td>
            <td>{props.product.name}</td>
            <td>{props.product.quantity}</td>
            <td>Rs.{props.product.price}</td>
            <td>%</td>
            <td>

                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                    Add Discount
                </button>
                <EditProduct Currentproduct={props.product.name}/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        );

    }

    export default class AddDiscount extends Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props)

            this.state={
                products:[]
            }
        }

        componentDidMount(){
            getProducts()
                .then(resultProducts=>{
                    this.setState({
                        products:resultProducts
                    })
                    console.log(resultProducts)
                });

        }

        productList=()=>{
            return this.state.products.map(Currentproduct=>{
                return <Product product={Currentproduct} key={Currentproduct._id}/>
            })
        }

        render(){
            return(
                <div>
                    <h3>Product Details</h3>
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead className="thead-light">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Product Category</th>
                                <th>Product Name</th>
                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                <th>Price</th>
                                <th>Discount</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {this.productList()}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )


   }
}
```

In the above code, I have used functional and class components in the same file, what I did is I have created a table which will have product details which comes from database and every single product is Iterated and displayed using Product component.

A product component displays required details for the table, I have also added a Add Discount button which displays a modal form with product details and a field to Enter the Discount. This modal form is developed inside EditProduct component.

I just sent the product name as the props to EditProduct component so that i can test if different data is displayed in the model form when we click the Add Discount button.

**My problem is when ever I click the button to Add New discount modal form only displays data from the 1st item in the table? Why is that, how can i change it?**

Please provide a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you sending the product data to the Discount Modal ? In a dummy application I created it seems to work fine https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-leftpad-ney1z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I am sending it as props.

Comment: Can you show the modal's code? Or, even better, create a runnable example on codesandbox or similar. My guess is that it's because you open the modal using regular "bootstrap way" (using `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter"`) and not the "react way". So the code only **shows** the modal but the part that should update the modal's content is missing.

Comment: Thank you @MoshFeu this works when i do it using React-bootstrap

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck